# Undefined method error associated with a particular method

Tags: ruby, methods

I've defined a method in a file called `utility.rb`. I've tried to call the method inside another file called `main.rb`. In `main.rb`, I did `require` that file by saying require `utility`, but when I ran `main.rb`, it gave me the undefined method error associated with that particular method. `utility.rb` and `main.rb` are in the same directory. Any idea?

Comment: it'd be helpful to post the code for both files if you can

Comment: @mportiz08 I "require"d other files as well, which works fine. There seems a difference between these other files and utility.rb that utility.rb itself is executable while others are not(i.e., only have definitions of methods, no calls). Would that result in the error?

Comment: not sure--it'd be nice to see the actual files for some context (also what ruby version you're using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a file `utility.rb` in any of your installed ruby libraries. This file is loaded instead of your one. Choose a more specific name for your file or add `.` to the beginning of your lib search path:

```
$:.unshift('.')
```